# Set checkbox default to true on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, default

I'm trying to set the default value of a check box to be true by default using `check_box` helper in Rails. I couldn't find the solutions in the [Rails api documentation](http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.0.2/doc/index.html?a=M001797&name=check_box)

This seems to be real easy with `check_box_tag`, but I need to use the above helper as I require it for a **model object**.

Is it possible to use check_box_tag for a model object..? Doesn't look to be so from the documentation.

Could you please suggest any javascript, jquery work arounds if I can't directly implement this in Rails.

I'm on `Rails 2.0.2` for project specific purposes.

Any guidance on this would be really handy..

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the checkbox is tied to one of your model's fields, all you need to do is set the value to true on your model:

In your controller:

```
def new
  @model = Model.new
  @model.my_value = true
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= f.check_box :my_value %>
```

Comment: Typically you would use a check_box with a boolean value, but I think it can also be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I made use of check_box_tag, as I was able to find an efficient workaround to suit my requirement with help..

This is how one could use the same:-

```
<%=check_box_tag "model[local_variable]",1,true %>
```

This probably shows how more versatile is check_box_tag ..

Comment: The only right solution here is whst @Dylan Markow have suggested

Comment: Why do you think so..?? Could you please tell me What is wrong with this alternative..?

Comment: The main idea is that your checkbox should rely on Model data. In your case it is ALWAYS checked even if real attribute is false. In real life I would improve @Dylan's answer this way: just set `my_value` to true by default in migration, so every new object will be with true attribute, while existing one will be just what it will

Comment: Do you mean to say if I "uncheck" the default "checked" box it would still carry a "true" value..? . Thats not the case.. I've verified this with the value passed in the log..

Comment: It means that it will be checked even if Model attribute is false

Comment: Okay, this could be my bad.. what if its just another variable and not a model attribute.. then for sure it should work fine.. i got the naming wrong.. would have to change the attribute term to a local variable..

Comment: If it doesn't belong's to Model - then ok. But you've wrote: `This makes check_box_tag also flexible to be used with model object`.

Comment: @boddhisattva: Please update your post with your findings. Posting it as an answer is less likely to help future visitors.